# RuntimeError from scipy.stats.mode on array of Timedelta: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Getting a RuntimeError from a unit test on the following code that has not been touched in quite a while and was previously I think running fine. Could this possibly be a bug in a new version of scipy?

```
from scipy import stats


def calc_time_delta(df, period1, period2):
    return df.ix[period2].name - df.ix[period1].name


def calc_periodicity(df):
    periods = []
    for i in range(7):
        periods.append(calc_time_delta(df, i, i + 1))
    return stats.mode(periods)[0][0]
```

Edit - MCVE would be:

```
from scipy import stats
from pandas import Timedelta

periods = [Timedelta('0 days 01:00:00'), Timedelta('0 days 01:00:00'), Timedelta('0 days 01:00:00'), Timedelta('0 days 01:00:00'), Timedelta('0 days 01:00:00'), Timedelta('0 days 01:00:00'), Timedelta('0 days 01:00:00')]

m = stats.mode(periods)[0][0]

# (<type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>, 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp', <traceback object at 0x10db2c830>)
```

I can actually fix the bug by replacing the original function with the following:

```
def calc_periodicity(df):
    periods = map(lambda i: calc_time_delta(df, i, i + 1).seconds, range(7))
    m = stats.mode(periods)[0][0]
    return timedelta(seconds=m)
```

i.e. the problem seems to lie with mode-ing pandas.Timedelta - but I am sure that that used to be possible. In any case, I have a workaround.

Comment: So the following works:

`    def calc_periodicity(df):`
`        periods = map(lambda i: calc_time_delta(df, i, i + 1).seconds, range(7))`
 `       m = stats.mode(periods)[0][0]`
`        return timedelta(seconds=m)`

Not sure why the original code started failing still..

Comment: Can you add sample `dataframe`? The best is use [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The problem could be in scipy or pandas.  What are the versions for which the problem occurs, and what were the versions where this worked?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with just pandas and numpy.  Start with the variables in your MVCE (thanks for that!), and then: `import numpy as np; p = np.asarray(periods); periods[0] > p`.  That comparison results in the infinite recursion.  (This is with pandas 0.17.1 and numpy 0.10.1.)

Comment: Issue submitted to the pandas repository on github: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11835

Comment: Thanks for doing that. As to versions, I am using the latest updates that come with Anaconda - [link](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) - as of today that would be pandas 0.17.1 and scipy 0.16.0.